# how to create wrapper scripts around another script in Unix shell scripting?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, wrapper

I have created two scripts (for eg pre.sh post.sh) in Unix ,which contain some critical commands. 
How do i make sure that these scripts run  at a particular timestamp only. 
I cannot add these to crontab. Can i create a wrapper script around these?, if yes please assist with examples for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a wrapper script like this.

wrapperscript.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/<user>/pre.sh
/home/<user>/post.sh
```

Then add this script in cron using:

```
crontab -e
```

This is the cron definition:

```
,----------------- minute (0-59)
| ,--------------- hour (0-23)
| | ,------------- day of month (1-31)
| | | ,----------- month (1-12) or use names
| | | | ,--------- day of week (0-7) (0 or 7 is Sun, or use names)
| | | | |
* * * * * /home/<user>/wrapperscript.sh
```